# Extract list of values from column that start with letter

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, excel-formula

My goal is to dynamically generate a list of all the values that start with specific letter in my 'Dashboard' sheet from a specific column in the dataset in 'Table1'.

[image: screenshot]

The [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/055La.jpg) demonstrates how I've manually done it for 'P'. Using the filter you can see all the highlighted values are replicated under the blue arrow (I see that Pancake is missing). The goal is to replicate this for the other letter in different columns.

I've tried looking into excel formulas (regular and array), however have yet to find a pythonic (I know this is not python) method of solving the problem.

The purpose of this is to generate a list that I can run a different macro on (green circle).

Comment: so if I get it correctly you want all the "MTSA" values under "M", and if there is an "FT" it should go under "F". Do you know in advance which letters you need or should that be dynamic?

Comment: That is correct. Ideally the letters in B4:K4

Answer (score 1):

For Excel 365 and data in column **A** between **A1** and **A26**, in **B1** enter:

```
=FILTER(A1:A26,LEFT(A1:A26,1)="P")
```

[image]

If your version of Excel does not support the `FILTER()` function, but does support `AGGREGATE()`, use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$26, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$999)/((LEFT(A$1:A$26,1)="P")), ROW(1:1))),"")
```

in **B1** and copy downward.

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe something like this ?

```
Sub test()
Set shTbl = Sheets("Table1")
Set shDash = Sheets("Dashboard")
col = Range("G1").Column
Set Rng = shDash.Range("B4", shDash.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))

With shTbl
.Cells.AutoFilter
For Each Cell In Rng
crit = "=" & Cell.Value & "*"
.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=col, Criteria1:=crit, Operator:=xlAnd
lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
.Range(.Cells(2, col), .Cells(lr, col)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Cell.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlValues)
Next
.Cells.AutoFilter
End With
End Sub
```

"Table1" is the sheet where the data to be filtered
`Range("G1").Column` is the column to be filtered in sheet Table1
"Dashboard" is the sheet where the first letter resides in row 4 starts from column B to the right.

Those variable values are based on your image attachment.

When the macro is run, it loop to each cell with the first letter in row 4 sheet Dashboard start from column B. Each first letter value then is used to filter column G in sheet Table1. Then it copy the filtered result to sheet Dashboard under that first letter.

That's if I'm not mistaken to get what you mean :).